# is copper a non-magnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I'm working on an optics project that I'm using Fresnel Equation for Intensity. but I've got a question, is copper a non-magnetic ?

You know because in Fresnel Equation, for non-magnetic materials which their refractive index is a real number, the formula is more simple.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Copper is a diamagnetic material.  Individual copper atoms have one unpaired electron in the valence shell, and thus might be considered paramagnetic, but when many copper atoms are combined into the bulk metal, their valence electrons are sent into a cloud that forms metallic bonds among the copper atoms, and the metal is diamagnetic.  All the answers given to this similar question explain the diamagnetic nature of copper in more detail: [Why is copper diamagnetic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59248/why-is-copper-diamagnetic)

Although a diamagnetic material opposes a magnetic field in which it is placed, most interact only very weakly with a magnetic field.  The diamagnetic property of copper metal is so weak that it is considered non-magnetic.

Comment: What is a copper molecule? Metal complex?

Comment: if it's know as non-magnetic, why does it have an ( imaginary number ) as its refractive index?

Comment: @t0xic: Sorry, I meant only Cu, not a molecule.

Comment: The refractive index is alway a real number, as is the extinction coefficient. I think you have something crossed in your mind here?!

Comment: @David2000: I see only real numbers for the refractive index of copper: http://www.filmetrics.com/refractive-index-database/Cu/Copper