# Diamagnetism question

Tags: physical-chemistry

I have a question why are some elements regarded as Diamagnetic despite having unpaired electrons, for example Sulfur  leaves 2 unpaired electrons yet it's considered diamagnetic, you would think it's paramagnetic upon first glance. Same thing happens with copper, why is that?

Comment: For copper, I think that it's a matter of distinguishing between Cu as an atom and Cu as a metal. A Cu atom does have an unpaired 4s electron, but for Cu metal I think that all those 4s electrons become non-localized electrons which participate in metallic bonding. Don't know about the situation with sulfur, though.

Answer (score 2):

The sulphur atom has two unpaired electrons, but solid sulphur is made up from $S_8$ rings that have no unpaired electrons, and it is therefore diamagnetic.

[image: Sulphur]

([picture from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_sulfur))

For the situation in copper see [Why is copper diamagnetic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59248/why-is-copper-diamagnetic)